# Better to create connections between related db columns using 'Index' or using a query?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, multiple-columns, relational

I'm wondering what would be the best way to create connections between related db columns - in a query or by using `Index`? I know that the primary concern with using `Index` is performance speed, and I don't believe that is an issue here.

Each column in the table represents various product attributes, and many of the columns are directly connected to a few other other columns (typically 2 - 3 columns), in one of these ways:

1. Alternate types of data for the same attribute *(i.e. color name + hex# displayed, or image name + .png file name + alt value)*. The values in these columns represent the same information but in a different format, so there's a direct correlation between the values but the values themselves aren't identical.
2. Subsets used for purposes of categorizing the values in a column. The same values exist in more than one column (with either a parent/child or sibling relationship).  *For example, the "Colors All" column is subdivided into 5 columns indicating different types of colors (i.e. Dark, Light, Bright, etc.), and most of those groups are further subdivided into 3 categories (ranked by degree of darkness, etc.). The color Navy is in 3 columns - "Colors All", "Dark Colors" and "Jewel Tones".*

In the past I've only used `Index` to create relationships between tables (using foreign keys), but it seems like this might save me from having to create statements connecting them each time.

At the moment I'm using mySql with PDO fetch statements (but I may be switching databases within the next 12 months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should start by clarifying that query and Index are not alternatives of each other.

When a table is created, columns are defined and some of these columns can be defined as FOREIGN KEYS, relating to other column(s) in another table. The relation between tables is only useful for referential integrity purposes (if the engine supports it). It's also useful for documentation purposes and some query designers use them to guess the joins in a query.

The indexes (or indices) serve a different purpose. They tell the database to create an additional data structure that servers to speed-up retrieval of rows base on values of the indexed columns.

So, FOREIGN KEYs define relationships between tables, queries join the related tables, and indexes speed up the joining, filtering, grouping, and sorting operations in a query.

Edit: A table is used to represent a type of entity. So, we could have a table for colors with two attributes: colors(color_name, color_value). Color_value could be an hex string or an integer representation. In principle, we would not have a column for the color code in format rgb(x,y,z) because this can always be computed from the first.

We would have another table to keep the list of images. However, there is no relation between the table of colors and the table of images.

Edit 2: The second type is usually represented with two tables. The first table stores a typical hierarchical relation and the second table tells which classes each colour is labelled with. So, your relational model for the examples you provide would be:

```
colors(colorid, color_name, color_value)
color_classes(classid, classname, parentid)
colors_classes(colorid, classid)

e.g.,
(colorid, color_name, color_value) - colors
(1,       'Navy',     'xxx')

(classid, classname,    parentid) - color_classes
(1,      'All colors',    0)
(2,      'Dark colors',   1)
(3,      'Light colors',  1)
(4,      'Jewel Tones',   2) -- assuming Jewel Tones is a subdivision of Dark Colors

(colorid, classid) - colors_classes
(1,       4)       -- assuming Jewel Tones is a subdivision of Dark Colors
```

You should also be aware that recursive relations (as in color_classes) are not gracefully handled in the relational model, but they are still quite common and there are solutions to deal with it.

Finally, I'm not sure that the relational model is indeed the best for your problem. It will depend on the use you want to make of the data.

Comment: This came up when I was trying to create arrays (either as multi-dimensional arrays or as sub-arrays), and someone on SO asked me if the columns are related in the db (if one of them was a name that points to the other two). I wasn't sure what they were referring to because I'd only used Foreign keys in the past, and didn't know that there was a way to have columns point to each other in the db so I did some research to try to figure out if there was a better or easier way to create relationships between the columns that I wasn't familiar with.

Comment: What's the relation between the arrays and the columns of a table? What are the arrays for?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about that ;-) Each array, or dimension in an array, represents a column in the db. They're used together in a lot of different ways throughout the site, including values which need are used together in the html attributes (i.e. color name + hex# displayed, or image name + .png file name + alt value), or for dynamically populating form elements.

Comment: So, it's an asset collection in which each item (color, image,...) is identified by a name?

Comment: Just to make sure that we're both referring to the same concept - Each column represents various product attributes. There are 2 types of directly connected columns. Type 1) Alternate types of data for the same attribute (i.e. info used to display colors, images of styles, etc.). While they represent the same information, the names for these are often different (i.e. color names & hex#'s)

Comment: Was too long, so had to split this up ;-) Type 2) The connection is slightly different - these are used to categorize the values in a column, and the same values exist in more than one column (i.e. The color 'Navy' is in 3 columns - 'Colors' (which includes every color), 'Dark Colors', and 'Jewel Tones').

Comment: But what I realized is probably the important thing, is that in both types the values in a few columns are directly related to the values in one column.

Comment: Do you already have this data stored in tables? Can you show examples in table format? I'm not sure we use the same terminology. I'll add more info to my answer. Also, I would suggest to put your updated information in the question itself.

Comment: Most of it isn't in tables yet (or at least not in a consistent format). Up until now I've been mostly working with them as hard-coded arrays, and now I'm trying to move them all into tables :-) But the structure that I've been using for the hardcoded arrays might help: $Colors = array('Navy' => 'Navy', 'Royal_Blue' => '#0000FF'); And I was just thinking the same thing, and am updating my question now :-)

Comment: I followed the 1rst 4 paragraphs, but then you kind of lost me :-( Can I trouble you to clarify that a bit (in particular the part about classes and recursive relations - I'm only just starting to learn about those)?

Comment: Please have a look here for a very nice explanation: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=recursive.php. I think you have the same situation with your color classification scheme.

Comment: I actually just read that posting :-D And I think you're right that I'm dealing with hierarchical relations :-) When I took another look at it now it just hit me that I might have misinterpreted your use of the term 'class' - are you referring to a group (instead of a css class)?

Comment: indeed, group or category.

Comment: Now it's starting to make sense :-) I'm going to reread everything

Comment: ok, good luck with it, I hope my answer replied to your question.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, and it's helping a lot of things fall into place :-D There are a few things which I'd like to clarify with you, but I want to do a bit more reading first (including rereading several of the articles that I'd previously read)